Error when uploading CSV file to Shiny app
I want to use a Shiny app where users can upload CSV files for high resolution melting analysis. However, I receive an error when uploading my data in app. How can I resolve this issue?
The CSV file consists of two rows: the first row contains temperatures, and the second row contains corresponding data output numbers.
I have an example file that works perfectly fine with the app. However the example file does like different from my file. I tried saving my file to match the example file but I don't know how. See picture.

I save my data by exporting my Excel file as a CSV UTF-8 format and then directly upload it into the app.
Any insights into what I could do so the app is able to run would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
The error is I receive is:
Warning: Error in xy.coords: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
  3: runApp
  2: print.shiny.appobj
  1: <Anonymous>

But the number of temperatures matches the corresponding data outputs. When I try to upload only the first 10 temperatures and outputs, I encounter a different error:
Warning: Error in smooth.spline: need at least four unique 'x' values
  1: runApp

My Data
df1 <- data.frame(Temperature = c(71.85, 71.79, 71.82, 71.79, 71.82, 71.79, 71.79,  71.82, 71.82), y = c(5.62, 5.68, 5.58,  5.57,  5.55, 5.55, 5.54,  5.51,5.52))

This is written in R and decimals are written as periods. My actual data is exported from an xlsx file to csv where decimals are written as decimals
Shiny app:
https://pavloh.shinyapps.io/hrmR/
From Pavlo Hrab (http://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.4491296)

  # Look at file upload, As soon as file is uploaded prepare the data and save it
  observeEvent(input$hmr,{
    # Read the first line and define the delimiter. Then read the whole data
    L <- readLines(input$hmr$datapath, n = 1)
    if (grepl(";", L)) vals$df <- read.csv2(input$hmr$datapath) else vals$df <- read.csv(input$hmr$datapath)
    # Drop NA columns
    vals$df <- vals$df[,colSums(is.na(vals$df))<nrow(vals$df)]
    write.csv(vals$df, file = "data.csv", row.names = F)
    
  })

  # Drop data from master dataframe (columns - individual results)
  observeEvent(input$drop,{
    to_drop <- input$drop_txt
    # First split the input by comma, then by range
    commas <- strsplit(to_drop, ",")
    ranges_drop <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(unlist(commas)[grepl("-", unlist(commas))], "-")))
    ind_col_drop <- trimws(unlist(commas)[!grepl("-", unlist(commas))])
    # Logic on how to split the data - like an individual column, or by range of columns. First go by ranges
    if (length(ranges_drop) > 0) {
      vals$df <- vals$df%>%
        select(!ranges_drop[1]:ranges_drop[2])
    }
    if (length(ind_col_drop) > 0){
      vals$df <- vals$df%>%
        select(-one_of(ind_col_drop))
    }

I tried uploading my data in the app expecting it to show my the melting curve analysis based of my data input. But I keep receiving errors.


Hey there, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question could be improved if you made it easy for us to reproduce your error. A self-contained shiny application along with a segment of your csv that we can copy and run would go a long way in helping us investigate your code :)

Hi, I would suggest posting a reproducible example so that SO can assist you. Having said that, I am going to guess that the warning you're receiving is from a plotting function, where data supplied to x and y are not equal in length.

@FelixJassler and sactyr thank you for your comments, I think I have done what you said!

You can add browser() inside observeEvent(input$hmr... or any other reactive function in order to stop the execution of your app and check how exactly the uploaded data is received. Maybe then you could make sure that the columns, rows, etc. are as expected, or add safeguards accordingly.
